# Avoiding Default CSS in ADF Application

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, oracle-adf

Is it possible to explicitly ask ADF application not to apply it's default Skins.
I tried removing skin family tags in trinidad-config.xml but still i can see applied CSS via firebug.
What I am trying is to not have ADF apply it's skins and ask a UI developer to use Bootstrap Framework with ADF/webcenter Application .

My thinking is these     < af > tags get converted to HTML , so if the conversion of tags to HTML components are known , then we can make the application look as we  want to.

Correct me If i'm thinking in wrong direction .

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing you can do is to use the simplest skins provided by ADF: `simple`. You can't remove all the ADF skinning.

Answer (score 0):

You can use -tr-inhibit:all to suppress default skinning.

Ultimately ADF does produce HTML but I think it will not be feasible to apply your approach since you don't really know what final HTML will look like.

Have you seen this? [WEBCENTER ADF TWITTER BOOTSTRAP THEME](http://www.johnbrunswick.com/2013/02/webcenter-adf-twitter-bootstrap-theme/)

In my personal experience it is not very ease to drastically change the look of an ADF application.

Answer (score -1):

When ADF decide to use templates for components then it will be possible to use css frameworks. They should consider to use at least one css framework because now adf is nightmare for designers.